# cmake check type size: sizeof(fd_set.fds_bits) in <sys/select.h>

Tags: select, cmake

I want to check `sizeof(fd_set.fds_bits)` in `<sys/select.h>` with cmake and output value into autoconfig.h
`CHECK_TYPE_SIZE("fd_set.__fds_bits" SIZEOF_FD_SET_FDS_BITS)` not given corrct result.
Is there any other way to implement it?

Comment: What do you mean by `CHECK_TYPE_SIZE` is not giving the correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression you use is incorrect:

```
fd_set.__fds_bits
```

In "C" language structure type **cannot be accessed** with dot (`.`) notation for extract its field.

Documentation for [CHECK_TYPE_SIZE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CheckTypeSize.html) suggests following way for determine size of the structure's field:

```
check_type_size("((struct something*)0)->member" SIZEOF_MEMBER)
```